# how to make an android application private

Tags: android, android-activity, extends

I am new to Android. Now I want my Android application to be private, so no others can access my code using astro file manager or some other tools.

Answer (score 2):

You could at the most try to obfuscate your code using Proguard. http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/proguard.html

This will make the reverse-engineering a lot harder for anyone.

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible, as soon as someone has your apk they can backward engineer it.